# Exception: Invalid instance in App.root in kivy when returning 2 values

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Kivy. I'm trying to create a background image with a TextInput on it. This is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class EmailInput(Widget):
    pass

class Minor(App):
    def build(self):

        img = Image(source = "cont/bg/bg.png")
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = True
        return img, EmailInput()


Minor().run()
```

Everytime I run it, it throws a critical error:

```
[CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 32, in <module>
     Minor().run()
   File "", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "", line 925, in _run_prepare
     raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
 Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

This is my .kv file:

```
<EmailInput>:
    TextInput:
```

I wonder if someone could help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using kivy you should connect Widget instances together.

Image and Label(the text you are willing to input) are subclasses of Widget, then you can conclude you should embed your image inside your label (background image).

As long as you embed the subclasses into each other, it should work.

Simple example :

```
<Screen>:
   orientation: "vertical"
   Label:
        text: "Example.."
        Image:
            source: 'kivy.png'
            y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 180
            x: self.parent.x
```

Answer (score 0):

`build` must return an instance of `Widget` or one of its subclasses, but you are returning a tuple of two widgets.

It sounds like you want to do something more along the lines of putting the TextInput on top of an Image, e.g. by adding them both to a parent FloatLayout.